# How to get animated svg to animate on Next.js App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to get an animated svg to animate on my next app. The svg appears on the site but it won't animate. The svg was created using SVGator and uses CSS and javascript to construct the animation. Here is how I've tried implementing it, but the Image tags in next don't seem to work:

```
      <Image
        className='absolute bottom-16 left-10'
        src={smile}
        alt='smile icon'
      />
```

Comment: A sample SVG image would definitely help. I suspect your SVG file contains `<svg>` markup + inline `<script>`. If that's the case, then you may need to extract that `<script>` and load it separately.

Answer (score 0):

*uses CSS and javascript*

W/ SVGator it's more like either - or... You can have both JS & CSS if there are text elements used & fonts included, yet in that case the animation is still JS-based.

Also to be kept in mind that JS will never play (work, run, render..) in an image  tag & CSS will be limited to fire on load as well (vs hover, for instance), so most probably however You'll try, current approach will not work.

Instead, You should use an object tag:

```
const Index = () => (
    <div>
        <object type="image/svg+xml" data="/animated.svg">svg-animation</object>
    </div>
);
export default Index;
```

Even better, You could serve Your SVG from CDN.

Btw, You can find all this info on [svgator](https://www.svgator.com/help/getting-started/add-animated-svgs-to-react-website) + there's a [test repo](https://github.com/SVGator/next-js/) as well.